# Отображение в режиме production для Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, настройка, symfony3

Здравствуйте!

Делаю тест на Symfony 3 (до этого работал с Laravel).

Никак не могу понять, как настроить отображение контента в prod-окружении.
Маршруты через `app_dev.php` отображаются нормально, а без него возвращается 500 ошибка.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где копать? Информации по этому вопросу на официальном сайте пока найти не удалось, а сроки поджимают.

В логе следующее:

```
[2016-04-18 09:13:08] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /address"" at D:\webdev\symfony\site.lc\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php line 123 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /address\" at D:\\webdev\\symfony\\site.lc\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener.php:123, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at D:\\webdev\\symfony\\site.lc\\var\\cache\\prod\\appProdUrlMatcher.php:46)"} []
```

Comment: в логах-то что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, всё дело в кэше.

Поскольку `prod` среда оптимизирована для скоростной работы, то конфигурация, маршрутизация и Twig-шаблоны компилируются в голые PHP-классы и кэшируются. Если вы изменили что-либо в `dev` среде и хотите посмотреть как это выглядит в `prod` среде, то вам нужно очистить кэш **этой среды** (`prod`); если этого не сделать, то вы увидите то, что откомпилировалось и закэшировалось ранее.

Очистить кэш в Symfony можно с помощью консоли:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Команда выше очистит кэш `dev` среды, так как по умолчанию консольные команды выполняются в ней (`dev` среде)

Чтобы очистить кэш для `prod` или другой среды, нужно добавить соответствующую опцию:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Альтернативный вариант:

```
php bin/console cache:clear -e prod
```

Источники:

- [The Symfony Book → Configuring Symfony (and Environments) → #Environments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/configuration.html#environments)
- [The Symfony Cookbook → Recipes about Console → How to Use the Console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/usage.html)