# Пагинация в Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, symfony3, pagination, постраничный-вывод

Как я уже [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514075/symfony-app-def-php-%D0%B8-production), делаю тестовое задание на Symfony 3.

В Laravel'овском построителе запросов есть метод [`paginate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#basic-usage), который позволяет просто и быстро делать постраничный вывод.

Никак не могу найти аналог в Symfony 3.

Неужели там нет такой необходимой вещи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте уточним, вы используете Doctrine ORM, для пагинации есть одно решение:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

$dql = "SELECT p, c FROM BlogPost p JOIN p.comments c";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
                   ->setFirstResult(0)
                   ->setMaxResults(100);

$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);

$c = count($paginator);
foreach ($paginator as $post) {
    echo $post->getHeadline() . "\n";
}
```

[взято отсюда](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html)

Answer (score 4):

Я отдаю предпочтение [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle)

**ШАГ 1:** Установка с помощью composer

```
composer require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle
```

**ШАГ 2:** Инициализация в kernel

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    return array(
        // Предыдущий код
        new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
        // Последующий код
    );
}
```

**ШАГ 3:** Добавляем в config.yml

```
knp_paginator:
page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
default_options:
    page_name: page                # page query parameter name
    sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
    sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
    distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
template:
    pagination: 'KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig'
```

**ШАГ 4:** Делаем запрос к БД в Controller и передаем в paginator

```
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $dql   = "SELECT a FROM AcmeMainBundle:Article a";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
    );

    // parameters to template
    return $this->render('AcmeMainBundle:Article:list.html.twig', 
        ['pagination' => $pagination]);
}
```

**ШАГ 5:** В template вставляем пагинатор в необходимом месте

```
<div class="navigation">
    {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
</div>
```

**ШАГ 6:** Наслаждаемся результатом

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle).

Простой в использовании и настройке, так же можно настроить как Вам удобно, документация так же [присутствует](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/templates.md).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.